# Makefile prefix logs with target name

Tags: makefile

We have rather complicated makefiles that make race condition debugging a nightmare due to the fact that multiple targets and being run at the same time. I'd like to prefix the logs with the target name and possibly with a timestamp as well.

Is this possible? We are using bash exclusively as the shell.

Comment: Do you mean that as "I am prepared to modify my makefile" or "is there a simple, one-line option"?

Comment: @Vroomfondel well, both would be interesting! But yes, both I would be prepared to do something.

Comment: Don't know if you tried this, but prefixing every recipe line with `@echo $@ &&` would print the name of the target which the respective line is helping to construct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any mechanism to automatically prepend the target to every line of output, but there is a make option [--output-sync](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) which groups all output from a target together.   This makes it much simpler to debug multi-threaded makes.   Note that nothing is output for a target until the target has completed, so if you have a long running target, it will delay the output.

As far as prepending the time, you can pipe your output to gawk:

```
make | gawk '{ print strftime("[%H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'
```